# Plot an array of plots as subplots with Plots.jl

Tags: julia, subplot, plots.jl

Continuation of this thread: [How to create an arbitrary number of subplots in Julia Plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196010/how-to-create-an-arbitrary-number-of-subplots-in-julia-plots)

When I tried

```
using Plots
plot_array = Any[] 
for i in 1:5
    push!(plot_array, plot(rand(10))) # make a plot and add it to the plot_array
end
plot(plot_array)
```

I received Error:

```
MethodError: no method matching Plots.Plot{Plots.PlotlyBackend}(::Char, ::Char, ::Char, ::Char, ...) 
Closest candidates are: Plots.Plot{Plots.PlotlyBackend}(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any)
```

What did  I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to "splat" the array of subplots in the last `plot` call using `...`:

```
using Plots
plot_array = [] 
for i in 1:5
    push!(plot_array, plot(rand(10)))
end
plot(plot_array...) # note the "..."
```

will produce something like

[image]